# How do In open IDLE?

Tags: python, minecraft

I want to make the whac-a-block on Minecraft Pi. It says I need to use IDLE, but I don't know how to get to it. Please help.

Comment: First link on google: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/python/

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Python 2 type idle in a command window.

If you are using Python 3 type idle3 in a command window.

If you are using a GUI there should be shortcuts to IDLE and IDLE3 on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal and type :

```
sudo apt install idle
```

when done installing , go back to terminal and type :

```
idle
```

IDLE will open up .